# split с несколькими разделителями в конце

Tags: java

Разбиваю строку на части
str.split(",");
Если в конце исходной строки есть две запятых подряд, то в выходном массиве этого участка нет вообще. А как сделать, чтобы в конце массива добавлялась пустая строка?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Заменим запятую на дефис для наглядности.
Исходная строка "1--2--". После split("-") получаем [1", "", "2"] А нужно [1", "", "2", ""]

Comment: используйте так `"1--2--".split("-", -1)`

Comment: Спасибо!
Отметить как правильный не могу, наверно репутации не хватает, еще не разобрался с сайтом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для таких задач есть перегруженный вариант метода `split` с двумя параметрами:

`String[] split(String regex, int limit)`

Если `limit` > 0, то длина возвращаемого массива будет не больше указанного количества элементов. Весть хвост будет помещен в один последний элемент. Разделители в конце игнорируются также как и в варианте с одним параметром.

Если `limit` = 0, то поведение как у варианта без второго параметра.

Если же `limit` < 0, причём само значение не важно, то разделители в конце породят пустые строки в конце массива, как вам и нужно.

Ответ на ваш вопрос: `str.split(",", -1)`